# Array for loop, placing data inside objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, for-loop

I have a function that create an array based on a number.
And i want to place a certain value inside each object of the array. But i am having problems with that.

Code:

```
updateNumberOfPointCards(number){
    this.pointCards.length = number.detail.value;
    for(let card of this.pointCards){
    card = {
      cardPoints: 0,
      cardValue: 0
    };
      console.log(this.pointCards);
    }
  }
```

when i see the console.log, the array is just empty. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Your pointcard array doesn't have any values in it. Is the for loop even working?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.length` to both cut down the array and extend the array to the length you want.

Your code will work fine for the cutting, but when an array is extended in that way, it is auto-filled with `undefined` objects, so your `let card...` for loop will not work.

You need to use an indexing for loop, and check whether the object is undefined or not before setting it, to prevent previous values being overwritten.

See this working snippet:

```js
pointCards = [{
  cardPoints: 3,
  cardValue: 2
}]

function updateNumberOfPointCards(number) {
  pointCards.length = number;
  for (let index = 0; index < number; index++) {
    if (pointCards[index] == undefined) {
      pointCards[index] = {
        cardPoints: 0,
        cardValue: 0
      };
    }
  }
}

updateNumberOfPointCards(5)
console.log(pointCards)
```

( you may need to add back in `this` or the shape of the variables to get it working in your project, but this should show you how the for loop needs to look)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create an array from a number, you can use `Array.from({ length: n })` where n is the number of items(length) you want.

For example, `Array.from({ length: 4 })` will create an array of length 4, containing 4 undefined items
i.e
`[undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined]`

You can then use `.map()` to transform it into an array of any shape or containing the objects you want

For example

```
Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, i) => ({         
    cardPoints: 0,
    cardValue: 0
}));
```

or `Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => i + 1)` will output an array of 10 items containing the numbers 1,2,3...10

You can basically use `Array.from()` to get an array of a specific length from a number and then map over it to get something more meaningful.

For more advanced use cases, check out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from